# Percent less sum (sum - $\%$)

Tags: calculus

How can i calculate this:

I have for example: $83$,$59$, and this value increase for $19\%$

I have tried so, but that is not true: 83,59-1/0,19

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, $$83,59 \times 1,19.$$

In case you meant to say *decrease*, $$83,59 \times 0,81.$$

Comment: I want to decrase 19% of every value

Comment: Then my second suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What is the 19% of 83,59? It is the value $x$ such that

$$83,59:100=x:19 $$

i.e.

$$x=\frac{83,59*19}{100}=15.8821\sim15.89. $$

If we see an increase of the 19%, then the final value will be

$$y=83,59+15,89=99.48.$$

If we expect a decrease of the 19%, then the final value will be

$$y=83,59-15,89=67.07.$$